# How can I cleanly express these dependencies?

Tags: object-oriented, dependencies, configuration, open-closed-principle

Consider this hypothetical scenario. I have a user form that has a collection of controls that are made available/unavailable based on certain criteria. One important criterion is product type. On selecting a product type, certain features on the form are made available. These features are also dependent on other criteria.

What is the clearest way I can represent this in OOP code? I'd like to be able to express this in such a way that an engineer can see a clear definition of which features are available per product type. I'd also like the ability to show, per feature, what criteria must be met to make that feature available. I'm torn between the following two options, represented as classes with collections of classes/an enum:

**Option 1**

- Product type A

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 2
- Product type B

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 3
  - Feature 4
- Product type C

  - Feature 2
- Product type D

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 4

**Option 2**

- Feature 1

  - Product type A
  - Product type B
  - Product type D
  - Additional criterion X
- Feature 2

  - Product type A
  - Product type C
  - Additional criterion X
  - Additional criterion Y
- Feature 3

  - Product type B
- Feature 4

  - Product type B
  - Product type D
  - Additional criterion Y
  - Additional criterion Z

I'd also like to design this to conform as closely as possible to the open-closed principle. It should be easy to add either a new product type or a new feature without modifying the existing code.

Since each concept (feature/product) has a dependency on the other, I'm struggling to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: What does the hierarchy in the bullet lists represent? Are these folders or subclasses or attributes?

Comment: These represent two different ways of expressing the problem domain.

Comment: It looks like a double entry box, but I don't know how to represent it with OOP.

Comment: "as closely as possible to the open-closed principle" - OK, you said that the part you want "open" is extensibility with regard to product types and features (and their availability criteria). What is the aspect that you want "closed" ("existing code" is too broad/vague)? The "open" part has to be placed as an extensibility point of the "closed" structure, you have to be more explicit about that.

Comment: Consider also the option to represent these as flat data pairs (product type, feature), pass that to the views, and then use that to enable/disable controls, or as an input to a factory to construct stuff on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without knowing what different type of criteria could be, but this is an aproximation.

- Have Feature implement `ConditionalFeature` interface
- `ConditionalFeature`s have `Criteria`
- `ConditionalFeature`s have `UIElements`
- A `Criterion` have `CriterionComponents`
- A `CriterionComponent` can be inspected to find out if it meets the criteria
- `Product` implements `CriterionComponent` interface
- Implementors of `ConditionalFeature` chek if all `Criteria` are met and toggle the `UIElement`s
- `CriterionComponent`s can be added to `Criteria`
- `Criteria` can be added to `ConditionalFeature` etc.

[image]